# Why 'helix-23.03-aarch64.AppImage' [in debian on x86_64 in Macbook Pro] is giving 'Exec format error'?

Tags: debian, exec, x86, file-format, appimage

It is on debian on x86_64

```
me@debian:~/bin$ chmod a+x helix-23.03-aarch64.AppImage
me@debian:~/bin$ ./helix-23.03-aarch64.AppImage
/tmp/.mount_helix-RyzFyw/AppRun: 4: exec: /tmp/.mount_helix-RyzFyw/usr/bin/hx: Exec format error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aarch64` AKA `ARM64` like the name suggests is the 64-bit extension of the ARM architecture family.

If you have "Intel x86_64" then you should look for `amd64`.

Comment: ChanganAuto: Sir: Thank you so much!

I downloaded a wrong format.

With all humility, I apologize for my ignorance!

Now, downloaded x86_64, and is working!